# Update using Linq query not working properly

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am new in Linq query and i get my user parameters from multiple text box to update a specific user in the Database but it's not working i try multiple way but they not work there no error but also there no update of the user

Code:

```
public void Update(UserEntity person)
{
    UserEntity user = new UserEntity();
    SurveyEntities dbcontext = new SurveyEntities();

    var query = (from p in dbcontext.Users
                 where p.UserId == person.UserId
                 select new UserEntity() { UserId =p.UserId , FirstName = p.FirstName, LastName = p.LastName, Birth = p.Birth.Value, Password = p.Password, UserName = p.Username, Email = p.Email, Active = p.Active.Value }).SingleOrDefault();

    query.FirstName = person.FirstName;
    query.LastName = person.LastName;
    query.UserName = person.UserName;
    query.Password = person.Password;
    query.Email = person.Email;
    query.Birth = person.Birth;
    query.Active = person.Active;

    try
    {
        dbcontext.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        // Provide for exceptions.
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of selecting a new UserEntity, just select p - then you have the entity to update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just try updating a projection when you do `select new`.
Instead, you should go for something like this:

```
var query = (from p in dbcontext.Users
                 where p.UserId == person.UserId
                 select p).SingleOrDefault();
```

And rest should be ok.

*Edit: For more info on Projection Operations (C#) and a more clear idea you can refer to:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693038.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

You can use context object and update value to save in database.

```
    public void Update(UserEntity person)
        {
            UserEntity user = new UserEntity();

            SurveyEntities dbcontext = new SurveyEntities();

          //  var query = (from p in dbcontext.Users
          //               where p.UserId == person.UserId
         //                select new UserEntity() { UserId =p.UserId , FirstName = p.FirstName, LastName = p.LastName, Birth = p.Birth.Value, Password = p.Password, UserName = p.Username, Email = p.Email, Active = p.Active.Value }).SingleOrDefault();

  UserEntity tmp=  dbcontext.UserEntity.where(x=>x.userId==person.UserId).FirstDefault();
                tmp.FirstName = person.FirstName;
                tmp.LastName = person.LastName;
                tmp.UserName = person.UserName;
                tmp.Password = person.Password;
                tmp.Email = person.Email;
                tmp.Birth = person.Birth;
                tmp.Active = person.Active;


            try
            {
                dbcontext.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                // Provide for exceptions.
            }


        }
```